# Why do convex polytope options constrict with dimension, rather than expand?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, big-picture, dimension-theory

There are an infinite number of regular polygons in the plane,
five regular polyhedra,
six regular polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^4$,
and then three regular polytopes in every dimension $d > 4$.

There are eight convex [deltahedra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltahedron) (all faces equilateral triangles),
five in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (see, "[Convex deltahedra in higher dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/a/149190/6094)"),
and then three deltatopes in every dimension $d > 4$.

> **Q**. Is there some intuitive reason why freedom is removed in higher dimensions?

I ask because, if I didn't know better, I would think the opposite.
There is vastly much more "room" in higher dimensions, and one might think forms proliferate, even under constraints. Concerning "much more room,"
think of the severe contraints on planar graphs vs.
the fact that *every* graph can be realized as embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I seek a corrective to my faulty intuition. Thanks!

Comment: I like Coxeter's book, Regular Polytopes. He wasn't just a pretty face.

Comment: Meanwhile, our own Jim Humphreys has a book http://www.math.umass.edu/~jeh/pub/book.html on Coxeter groups and reflection groups that probably gives a complete answer.

Comment: "Regular" seems like a more important adjective than "convex" in the title. Anyway, my intuition is that while the amount of room might increase, it doesn't increase as quickly as the number of constraints imposed by regularity. Graph embeddings, on the other hand, don't have to have any kind of symmetry properties.

Comment: Excellent point, @QiaochuYuan! I wonder if that intuition can be made more precise, that constraints outrun freedom...?

Comment: A rough estimate of the number of constraints is that an $n$-simplex has $n!$ flags, and regularity means that the symmetry group acts transitively on flags.

Comment: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/integers/integers_4.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a well known "dimension curse" phenomenon. It is easier to explain for spherical polyhedra.  Let $P$ be a regular spherical convex polyhedron of dimension $d$. Starting with dimension $d=3$, all spherical convex polyhedra are rigid, so they are determined by their links (intersection of a vertex cones with an $\epsilon$-sphere).  The latter are themselves regular (spherical) polyhedra.  Therefore, for $d\ge 4$ these links are rigid themselves and regular polyhedra are uniquely determined by their links (which are all congruent, of course, by regularity).  Thus, as dimension grows the combinatorial types of regular polyhedra can disappear but new cannot appear.

For Euclidean polyhedra the same type of analysis works, but goes through the links which are spherical polyhedra.  Therefore, as regular spherical polyhedra disappear so do Euclidean ones, but this is less intuitive perhaps.  I haven't seen "deltatopes" before, but it's the same story there as well, if I understood definitions correctly.